# Javascript functions not working after changing html with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html that uses a couple of JS functions inside a div. If I change the content of that div with the help of JS and innerHTML to some other html code that also has some JS functions, they stop to work. if I then change back to the previous html it still doesn't work.

Its like the javascript is unbound to all the elements that had the function as soon as the html in a div is updated.

I know I can solve this with hiding and showing layers but I would prefer not to do this.

For the moment I have solved this by injecting the js file every time the html of that div is changed using this code:

```
function inject(src, cb, target){
    target = target || document.body;
    var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
    s.charset = 'UTF-8';
    if(typeof cb === 'function'){ 
        s.onload = function(){
            cb(s);
        }; 
        s.onreadystatechange = function () {
            (/loaded|complete/).test(s.readyState) && cb(s);
         };                     
    }
    s.src = src;
    target.appendChild(s);
    return s;
};
```

This how ever loads a new line in the html file every time I update the html which doesn't seem like a very elegant solution.

Is there a way to make the javascript I have reload or keep its connections when I change the html without reloading the page?

Comment: Try jQuery's trigger method. `$('#YourDivContainingScript').trigger('create')`

Comment: Can you post some code of how you change the HTML? Maybe a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

to execute js code you can directly use `eval()` it will execute js immediately, irrespective of html or dom structural changes.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: do you have a better suggestion @LightStyle?